# Horizontal line through heading title stopped working

Tags: html, css

I previously had horizontal lines on either side of my heading titles, however it has now stopped working and the line is displayed on top of the text, please help! The code I used for this and worked absolutely fine is below;

```
h6.two span {
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;   
}

h6.two+p {
border-top: solid 1px black;
padding-top: 12px;
margin-top: -12px;
}
```

[Can see the problem here](http://www.institute101.com)

Comment: it is working well... whats your problem?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I want the text to be infront of the horizontal line. So I want horizontal lines on either side of the text.

Comment: So if it used to work, what changed?

Comment: I think it happened after installing a font changer plugin....I deactivated the plugin but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what changed for you, but the way I'd do it (with more specificity in regards to selectors, of course) would be:

```
h6 {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

That way, you can set a block with a solid background to always exist on top of the line.

Comment: I just edited it, with your suggestion but not sure if I did it correct, its not working - h6.two span {background: #fff;display:inline-block;position: relative;z-index: 1;padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500; 
  }
  
h6.two+p {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-top: -12px;
  }

Comment: Someone helped me do this before, so my knowledge is limited, can you please explain a little more about how I could use your method?

Comment: Block level elements will fill the width of the parents and allow for size manipulation (height, width, padding). Inline-block elements act much in the same way, except they are only the width of their content when initialized. So imagine a physical block that sits behind your text. From there, you add the background color. Z-index will push it on top of its immediate siblings, ie the `p` tag. Z-index is not, however, possible without `position`ing (relative, absolute, fixed).

Comment: Very helpful thank you, but I've been trying to implement it but it's not working. So from what I understand I would not need to use +p and span?

Comment: I'd suggest encapsulating a span and a p inside the h6 tag, yeah. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uLtAH/

Answer (score 0):

The reason mine stopped working was because, I went to edit my home page in Visual mode and the span tags were automatically deleted.